# Upload jrxml which runs on a mdx query

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I successfully developed a report in iReport, which runs against a mondrian cube and a mysql data source.

When i upload this report jrxml to jasperserver as a resource > jasperreport, i dont see any options to specify the mondrian schema. It gives option to add data source.
Running this report doesnt yield any data or error?

Has anyone uploaded a report which has mdx as a query. 
ps:I am using jasperserver community edition

Comment: We tried to implement a bean data source as [described](http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=112&forumid=102&topicid=16327&page=1) . But for some reason, jasperserver did not recognize the bean source. We have given up on jaspersoft and instead moved to pentaho bi. Pentaho bi integrates very well with its report designer. I would recommend it over jaspersoft.

Answer (score 1):

I saw you have switch to Pentaho but if someone face the same issue there is a trick to succeed.

There are 2 means to link a mondrian cube with jasperserver (for the 4.5CE version at least):

- use the JasperReport Server repository in iReport to upload the report, in the ui you can choose your mondrian connexion (previously created in jasperserver) as datasource.
- use JasperServer to upload the report and manualy enter the id of the mondrian connexion.

Comment: The first trick worked for me on 5.0 CE too. Just to clarify: if you edit the report, on the *Data Source* tab you can write something like @/analysis/connections/SugarCRM@ which is a simple *Mondrian connection*. The confusing thing is that these are not available to select on the *Browse* button.